# how to handle form in php with MVC structure?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

i have a control.php here. Which control other php like, salesmonitor.php (which will be called when I click the link in the NAV). I have created a separate file to upload information to the database which will be called by the controller which is sm_add_pm.php.

this is inside my parent folder

-> model (nothing inside yet)

-> views (contains: home.php, add_pm_to_db.php, salesmonitor.php, addpm.php)

-> control.php

```
$request = $_GET['id'];

switch($request)
{
   case 'hm':
   home();
   break;

   case 'sm':
   salesmonitor();
   break;

   case 'sm_view_pm':
   salesmonitor();
   break;

   case 'sm_add_pm':
   addpm();
   break;

   default:
   default_function();
   break;
}
```

the link now looks like this

```
control.php?id=sm_add_pm
```

inside of that, there is a form. i cannot proceed to my php file which will input the value into the mysql database.

```
<form action="add_pm_to_db.php" method="post">
<input class="form-control" id="ex1" type="text" maxlength="2" name="month"/>
<input class="form-control" id="ex2" type="text" maxlength="2" name="day"/>
<input class="form-control" id="ex1" type="text" maxlength="2" name="year"/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" style="margin-top:25px; width:100%;">Add</button>
</form>
```

the problem is, every time i click "ADD" button, it does not proceed to add_pm_to_db.php. is that because i'm on the control.php? if so, how can I get to add_pm_to_db.php?

Thanks in advance for answering my problem. Thanks also the stackoverflow community.

Comment: Button type needs to be `submit`.

Comment: thank you sir. I overlooked my problem ^_^ anyways, I changed it after you comment and I get another error which is URL NOT FOUND, and change the action to this "  action="view/add_pm_to_db.php"  " and it works. Thanks for the help sir Jon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use button type="submit", so it will pass the data via post (your method) to the prefered php script:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" style="margin-top:25px; width:100%;">Add</button>
```

You should use add_pm_to_db.php as some kind of an model (beacouse it will put your data to db), and use controller for handleing various types of id's in your case...

Hope this will help you.